# Перестала работать программа

Tags: qt, c++, visual-studio

Даже не знаю в чем проблема. я не могу ее решить.

Писал я программу в visual studio 2012 на qt c++. Вышел на 5 минут. Прихожу запускаю компилицию программы. Компиляция прошла успешно. Но сама программа не работает. Оказалось, что мой сосед по комнате, что-то нажал или не нажал (вообщем он не может толком объяснить).
Интересный факт, что никаких ошибок не возникает во время работы программы. Просто она отказывается выполнять нужное действия.

Я уже по привычке постоянно делаю копии проектов, вот и на этот раз сделал ее за 30 минут до выхода с комнаты. Тоесть я потерял очень мало кода. Конечно же я заменил неработающий проет на мою копию. Скомпилировал и проблема повторилась.

Также я заметил, что размер exe-шника уменьшился примерно на 20 кб. Если раньше он был около 70 кб, то теперь 50 кб. Речь идет об еxe-шнике релиза, а не дебага. Я предмолагаю, что именно через уменьшения размера программа не работает как должна. Никаких других изменений я не заметил.

В чем может быт проблема, кто сталкивался?. Помогите пожалуйста, я буду очень благодарен.

Любой совет пожалуйста.

Comment: Маловато сведений. Что значит не работает? Не запускается или что-то не срабатывает в процессе? Не работает сама по себе или же при запуске Run из среды та же ситуация? Проверяли ли журнал сообщений винды? У меня с qt был такой финт, все хорошо но прога не запускается вне среды причем без ошибок, то что не хватает длл (причем похоже не экзешнику а уже самим библиотекам) выяснилось только из лога винды.

Comment: Не хватило символов :( Вообще подозреваю что ваш товарищ нажал очистку проекта либо же запустил qmake, а ошибка у вас в коде уже сидела некоторое время, просто не проявлялась т.к. что-то нужное застряло в объектниках или файле сборки, со студией такого не было, но вот с makefile  было, принцип думаю тот же

Comment: @aknew, я сам переодически нажимая очистку проекта. Ошибок в коде быть не может т.к я сделал копию полностью работоспособного проета. Не работает значит запускаеться, но не хочет исполнять оперецию передачи данных с помощью сокету. Программа и в среде и без нее не запускается. Все dll файлы добавлены.

Comment: вообще лучше не копию делать, а пользоваться системой контроля версий, оно бы заодно показало что именно изменилось в настройках\коде проекта.

Comment: @aknew, можно поподробнее о qmake? кстати я пишу проет в vs, а не в qt creator

Comment: про qmake все относительно просто - дело в том что qt использует не совсем c++ (сигналы-слоты, ресурсы и т.п.) и компиляторы его собрать не могут, потому перед компиляцией проходит дополнительный этап qmake который преобразует код из вашего проекта где используются спецфинты qt превращается в обычный c++ код (там используется еще ряд программ,но в ручную вы их не вызываете) который уже и скармливается компилятору. Проблема в том что при изменении состава модулей в проекте этот самый qmake нужно запустить вручную иначе он продолжает линковать со старым списком модулей.

Comment: Соотвественно, если вы когда-то давно меняли модули но не дергали qmake есть риск что был случайно снесен какой-то нужный модуль, но все работало пока кто-то не запустил qmake. Хотя в таком случае скорее бы не собралось. чем что-то еще

Comment: @aknew модули, содержимое, имена файлов и т.д не менялись. Только размер exe уменьшился